# Vagrant Connection timeout

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

So after running vagrant up on my Linux Mint machine, I'm getting this output:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying..
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

I've been looking for solution, and everywhere seems to point to enable virtualization in the bios. The problem is, there's no option to do that in my bios, on Toshiba L75D-A7283. Funny thing is, I am actually able to run different virtual machines, such as Windows 7 using virtual box, without any problems. The only issue that I have is during vagrant up and this connection timeout. Is there anything else I can do about this?

```
Vagrant version: Vagrant 1.7.4
VirtualBox version: 5.0.8
```

Comment: Show your Vagrantfile

Comment: It is the Laravel's homestead.

Comment: Show it, link it. We're lazy.

Comment: I suggest to enable the gui (have a look at the Vagrantfile) and to see what's happening during boot.

Comment: Sure, I'll try with the GUI thing. The problem is, that at work I can run different  vagrant machines without any problems, so I'm sure that the problem is in my laptop.

Comment: OK, I tried, and this is the message that I get: "VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot." I guess nothing can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the connection timeout problem after updating to the mentioned versions of VB and Vagrant with ubuntu/trusty64 guest machine , and finally this fixed my problem:

It turns out that as I was messing around with getting the machine to load (due to Virtualization technologies being disabled), I clicked one too many items on the image settings page.

To fix this, go to the "Settings" page for the virtual machine, and click "System". Under the "motherboard" options, be sure that "Enable EFI (special OSes only)" is unchecked. Then click "OK", and try to boot the machine again. The option that was checked is basically how you get into the EFI Interface.

https://askubuntu.com/a/162149

Comment: There's no indication that OP messed with settings like you did, so I don't think this is an answer.

Comment: I will definitely check this out when I get home.

Comment: Enabling EFI didn't really help me. When I try to boot directly from Virtualbox I get this message: VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.

Comment: although it seems you have a different problem , the above link is saying to "disable" EFI, not enable it. @Zed

Comment: yeah, it is disabled by default, tried off and on, same thing. I gave up like 5 minutes ago.